# 400 Error Invalid Recipient Err Microsoft Graph API

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying send email through Microsoft graph api. I created a message object like the following.
`{"message":{"subject":"hellowolrd","body":{"contentType":"text","content":"wow"}},"toRecipients":{"emailAddress":{"address":"example@yahoo.com"}}}`

But gets 400 error with invalid recipient. Can anybody help me why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a syntax issue in your JSON request.Look closely after content you have an extra closing **}** which means you are not posting '*toRecipients*' in the message.

{"message":{"subject":"hellowolrd","body":{"contentType":"text","content":"wow"}**}**,"toRecipients":{"emailAddress":{"address":"example@yahoo.com"}}}

Instead try below JSON to make it work -
{
"message": {
"subject": "hellowolrd",
"body": {
"contentType": "text",
"content": "wow"
},
"toRecipients": [
{
"emailAddress": {
"address": "example@yahoo.com"
}
}
]
}
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The invalid recipient was caused by a different json structure. I had to exactly match the following structure that was provided in one of their example.

```
 $mailArgs ='
{
    "message": {
        "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "Text",
            "content": "Lunch Invited"
        },
        "toRecipients": [
            {
                "emailAddress": {
                    "address": "example@example.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    }';
```

So I created a JSON array to match exactly the same structure and it worked!